# Azure : How to clone sql virtual machine

Tags: sql, azure

I am trying to clone a SQL VM to another resource group,

Cloning a normal VM is simple,

1. Create disk snapshot (OS & data Disks)
2. Create Disk from snapshot
3. create VM from managed Disk

The image I have is (image: Sql Server 2019 Standard on Windows Server 2022-Gen2), following the above steps only creating a vm but not SQL Virtual Machine.
Please let me know if anyone knows the correct steps or any documentation.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform this activity through PowerShell. Please go through below steps-
To create a snapshot using the Azure portal, complete these steps, you can skip this if you have already created a snapshot.

1. In the Azure portal, select Create a resource.
2. Search for and select Snapshot.
3. In the Snapshot window, select Create. The Create snapshot window appears.
4. For Resource group, select an existing resource group or enter the name of a new one.
5. Enter a Name, then select a Region and Snapshot type for the new snapshot. If you would like to store your snapshot in zone-resilient storage, you need to select a region that supports availability zones. For a list of supporting regions, see Azure regions with availability zones.
6. For Source subscription, select the subscription that contains the managed disk to be backed up.
7. For Source disk, select the managed disk to snapshot.
8. For Storage type, select Standard HDD, unless you require zone-redundant storage or high-performance storage for your snapshot.
9. If needed, configure settings on the Encryption, Networking, and Tags tabs. Otherwise, default settings are used for your snapshot.
10. Select Review + create.

Moving snapshot of SQL Virtual Machine under different resource group in another subscription
PowerShell:

#Provide the subscription Id of the subscription where snapshot exists
$sourceSubscriptionId='yourSourceSubscriptionId'

#Provide the name of your resource group where snapshot exists
$sourceResourceGroupName='yourResourceGroupName'

#Provide the name of the snapshot
$snapshotName='yourSnapshotName'

#Set the context to the subscription Id where snapshot exists
Select-AzSubscription -SubscriptionId $sourceSubscriptionId

#Get the source snapshot
$snapshot= Get-AzSnapshot -ResourceGroupName $sourceResourceGroupName -Name $snapshotName

#Provide the subscription Id of the subscription where snapshot will be copied to
#If snapshot is copied to the same subscription then you can skip this step
$targetSubscriptionId='yourTargetSubscriptionId'

#Name of the resource group where snapshot will be copied to
$targetResourceGroupName='yourTargetResourceGroupName'

#Set the context to the subscription Id where snapshot will be copied to
#If snapshot is copied to the same subscription then you can skip this step
Select-AzSubscription -SubscriptionId $targetSubscriptionId

#Store your snapshots in Standard storage to reduce cost. Please use Standard_ZRS in regions where zone redundant storage (ZRS) is available, otherwise use Standard_LRS
#Please check out the availability of ZRS here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/Az.Storage/common/storage-redundancy-zrs#support-coverage-and-regional-availability
$snapshotConfig = New-AzSnapshotConfig -SourceResourceId $snapshot.Id -Location $snapshot.Location -CreateOption Copy -SkuName Standard_LRS

#Create a new snapshot in the target subscription and resource group
New-AzSnapshot -Snapshot $snapshotConfig -SnapshotName $snapshotName -ResourceGroupName $targetResourceGroupName